# Beta between stock and option

Tags: black-scholes, probability, covariance

In Black Scholes model I would like to compute
$$
\beta_K = \frac{\mathrm{cov}(C_{K,T},S_T)}{\mathrm{cov}(S_T,S_T)} = \frac{\mathrm{cov}((S_T - K)^+,S_T)}{\mathrm{cov}(S_T,S_T)}
$$
with respect to say risk-neutral measure. Here $C_{K,T}$ is the payoff of the call with expiry $T$ and strike $K$ at expiry, and $S_T$ is the price of the underlying at expiry. Of course, this all can be computed just by using the log-normal distribution of $S_T$, however I wondered whether there is some trick to compute it in a faster way.

Motivation: I would like to know which $\beta_K = \Delta$ minimizes the variance of $C - \Delta S$. That is, if you can't hedge dynamically, but only once, would you still choose the BS delta, or whether it is gonna be something else.

Comment: I assume that you don't want to calculate the covariance of $(S_T-K)^+$ with $S_t$ but rather of $E[(S_T-K)^+|F_t]$ ...

Comment: @Richard: I don't have small $t$ at all. I'd like to compute the covariance as of now of the expiration values. Let me add some motivation.

Answer (score 1):

For the terminal distributions, I don't have the closed-form solution to hand, but it's computable, since we can price power options (with payoffs like $(S_T^n-K)^+$).  You need to find

$$
E[S_T C_{K,T}] = \int_K^\infty x(x-K) \cdot p_{BS}(x) dx \\=-Ke^{(r-q)T} C_{K,T} + \int_K^\infty x^2 \cdot p_{BS}(x) dx
$$

The latter formula is just a power-option price, which is a common homework problem whose solution can be found in many places, including [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.0599).

If an instantaneous treatment is good enough, then you really just need to know the instantaneous volatility $\omega$ of an option $C$ to compute this.  If you are willing to believe Black-Scholes, you can apply Ito's Lemma to find that

$$
C \cdot \omega = \Delta \cdot S \cdot \sigma_S
$$

*Edit:* added terminal distribution integrals and comments on instantaneous versus terminal

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Under the Black-Scholes' setting (i.e., constant interest rate, dividend yield, and volatility), an analytical formula is possible.

Comment: I see, essentially this looks similar to just straightforward computation through the log-normal density, and is a bit brute-force. Regarding you second ('instantaneous') approach, how do we get this equation through Ito Lemma? I mean, which differential do we start with? I know we get
$$
  \mathrm dC = \sigma_tS_t\mathrm dW_t
$$
but not sure how to get your equality.